# Burninate "knowledge-base"

Tags: discussion, tags

The [knowledge-base](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-base) tag seems useless, for lack of a better word. Five questions, different topics (mostly not related to Microsoft's "Knowledge Base"), no tag description or wiki, ...

Let's get rid of it.

Comment: "for lack of a better word" -- well, you could look up a better word in a knowledge-base.  Oh wait, we just removed that.  :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I typically wait for feedback on these, most of the questions are product/learning materials/service recs and were closed on review.

The tag has been removed.